How to evaluate $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^k \right)}{n^2}$?
Context: While playing around with binomial coefficients, I came across the sum $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \dbinom{n}{k}^k$, which caught my interest. I doubt that there is a closed form for any $n$. This sum appears to grow very rapidly as $n$ increases, prompting me to explore its behavior more deeply. Specifically, I began investigating the asymptotic behavior of its logarithm, focusing on the limit
$$\displaystyle\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^k \right)}{n^2}.$$

Numerical tests suggest that this limit converges, but proving this rigorously or finding the exact value of the limit has been challenging.

$$\frac{\ln\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{1,000} \dbinom{1,000}{k}^k \right)}{1,000^2}\approx 0.4251119992068337$$


Here is a graph of $\displaystyle\frac{\ln\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \dbinom{n}{k}^k \right)}{n^2}$ for $1\le n \le 500$


I attempted to use Stirling's approximation to simplify the terms, but the calculations became quite complicated. I also explored applying the Stolz-Cesàro theorem, but without success.

Heuristics. Note that, by Stirling's approximation,
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}\log\left[\binom{n}{pn}^{pn}\right] = p H(p), $$
where $H(p) = -p\log p -(1-p)\log(1-p)$ is the binary entropy function. So, it is reasonable to believe that
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}^k \approx n \int_{0}^{1} e^{pH(p)n^2} \, \mathrm{d}p, $$
which would then imply that the desired limit is
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}\log\left[\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}^k \right] = \max_{p\in[0,1]} pH(p) \approx 0.4276362127321249214 . \tag{*} $$

Rigorous proof. We first establish the following lemma:

Lemma 1. Assume that $(a_{n,k})_{k \in [0:n]; n \in \mathbb{N}_0}$ is a double sequence of positive numbers such that the following conditions hold:
Condition: There exists a continuous function $f : [0, 1] \to (0, \infty)$ such that $a_{n,k_n} \to f(p)$ for any $p \in [0, 1]$ and for any sequence $(k_n)_{n\geq 0}$ such that $k_n/n \to p$.
If $(N_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is any sequence of positive integers such that $\log n \ll N_n$ as $n \to \infty$, then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{N_n} \log\left[ \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_{n,k}^{N_n} \right] = \max_{p \in [0, 1]} \log f(p). $$

Before delving into the proof of the lemma, let us check that this indeed implies $\text{(*)}$. To this end, we set
$$ a_{n,k} = \binom{n}{k}^{k/n^2}, \qquad f(p) = e^{pH(p)}, \qquad N_n = n^2. $$
Then for any $p \in [0, 1]$ and for any $(k_n)$ such that $k_n / n \to p$, Stirling's approximation gives
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n,k_n} = f(p). $$
Then $\text{(*)}$ is an immediate consequence of Lemma 1. So we turn to the proof of the lemma. In doing so, the following observation is useful:

Lemma 2. Let $(f_n)_{n\geq 0}$ and $f$ be real-valued functions on $[0, 1]$ such that

$f$ is continuous on $[0, 1]$, and
$f_n(x_n) \to f(x)$ whenever $x_n \to x \in [0, 1]$.

Then $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$.

Proof of Lemma 2. Assume otherwise. Then there exist $\varepsilon > 0$, an infinite subset $J$ of $\mathbb{N}_0$, and a subsequence $(x_j)_{j\in J}$, such that $|f_j(x_j) - f(x_j)| \geq \varepsilon$. Since $[0, 1]$ is sequentially compact, by passing to a further subsequence if necessary, we may assume that $(x_j)_{j\in J}$ converges to some point $x \in [0, 1]$. Then by the continuity of $f$, $|f(x_j) - f(x)| \to 0$ as $j \to \infty$. Hence,
$$ |f_j(x_j) - f(x)| \geq \underbrace{|f_j(x_j) - f(x_j)|}_{\geq \varepsilon} - \underbrace{|f(x_j) - f(x)|}_{\to 0}, $$
and it follows that $f_j(x_j)$ cannot converge to $f(x)$, a contradiction. $\square$
We can now proceed to the proof of the lemma:
Proof of Lemma 1. For each $n$, define $f_n(x)$ as
$$ f_n(p) = a_{n,\lfloor np\rfloor}. $$
Then for any $p \in [0, 1]$ and for any $p_n \to p$, the sequence $k_n = \lfloor np_n\rfloor $ satisfies $k_n/n \to p$, and so, $f_n(p_n) = a_{n,k_n} \to f(p)$. So by Lemma 2, $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[0, 1]$. Let $m_n = \max_{k\in[0:n]} a_{n,k}$ be the row-wise maximum of $(a_{n,k})$. Then the uniform convergence implies that
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} m_n
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \max_{p\in[0,1]} f_n(p)
\to \max_{p\in[0,1]} f(p). $$
On the other hand,
$$ m_n^{N_n} \leq \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_{n,k}^{N_n} \leq n \cdot m_n^{N_n}, $$
hence
$$ \log m_n \leq \frac{1}{N_n} \log \left[ \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_{n,k}^{N_n} \right] \leq \log m_n + \frac{\log n}{N_n}. $$
Since $\log n \ll N_n$, we can invoke the squeezing lemma to deduce that
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{N_n} \log \left[ \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_{n,k}^{N_n} \right]
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \log m_n
= \log \Bigl( \lim_{n\to\infty} m_n \Bigr)
= \log \max_{p\in[0,1]} f(p)
= \max_{p\in[0,1]} \log f(p) $$
as desired. $\square$

Really nice. Originally, I studied the maximizer $k^\ast(n)$ of $f(k) := \binom{n}{k}^k$ subject to $k\in \mathbb{R}$, $k\in [0, n]$. In numerical experiment, it seems the quantity $\frac{k^\ast(n)}{n}$ increasing as $n$. When $n = 10^6$, the maximizer $\approx 0.7035 n$. Now according to your solution, perhaps $\frac{k^\ast(n)}{n}$ converges to $p^\ast$ which is the maximizer of $pH(p)$ (also a solution of $(1-p)^{2p-1} = p^{2p}$). Even this is true, it may not be easy to prove it directly.  Also, I am curious if the maximum of $\binom{n}{k}^k$ is studied before? (see next comment.)

I want to know if the following is true: $\binom{n}{k}^k \le n^n \binom{n}{p^\ast n}^{p^\ast n}$ for all $k\in [0, n]$.
The point is that for any small $\epsilon$, it is not true that
$\binom{n}{k}^k \le n^n \binom{n}{(p^\ast-\epsilon)n}^{(p^\ast-\epsilon)n}$ for all $k\in [0, n]$. On the other hand, it is true that $\binom{n}{k}^k \le n^{n^2} \binom{n}{p^\ast n}^{p^\ast n}$ for all $k\in [0, n]$. I don't know if $n^n$ is enough large.
(Even it is true, it may not be easy to prove it as well.) What's your opinion? Thanks.

（to avoid misunderstanding) By the way, I noticed someone downvoted you after I gave a comment. It is not me who downvoted you. (Already upvote some days ago.)

@RiverLi, Sorry I didn't respond to your question. I don't have a good idea about the inequality, either. I also originally tried to locate the maximum point using the Stirling's approximation and use that for obtaining a bound, but this did not lead anything useful (or I might have made silly mistakes in my computation). I'll give it another look! Also, I know you didn't downvote :)

Thanks. Perhaps this is not a feasible direction since even with Stirling's approximation, it is not easy to locate the maximizer (or prove the inequality).

$$a_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^k$$
is A167008 from the On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences®. The OEIS entry states that
$$
 \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n^{1/n^2} = (1-r)^{-r/2} \approx 1.5336280651
$$
where $r \approx 0.7035060764$ is the root of the equation $(1-r)^{2 r-1} = r^{2r}$, the source is

Vaclav Kotesovec, Interesting asymptotic formulas for binomial sums.

It follows that
$$
 \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln a_n}{n^2} = -\frac r2 \cdot \ln(1-r) \approx
0.4276362127 \, .
$$

I have some trouble following that paper it seem to relay on mathematica a lot and I am not familiar with it, I am unable to find the proof  also how can you read oeis? It seems impossible for me to read since it doesn't use latex and it is written in a weird notation/latex

@pie: I am not sure if that paper contains full/rigorous proofs. As I understand it, the asympotics is computed by determining the contribution of the “most significant terms” in the series. But I hope that this answer helps as a reference, so that you or someone else can figure out a complete proof and post it here. – OEIS uses a very simple ASCII notation for everything, including formulas. But actually I find that easy to read, which part is unclear to you?
